# UIImage not displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimage, uitabbaritem

I am using iOS 7 SDK and Xcode 5. I want to set icons on UITabBarItem. I am using below method.

```
setFinishedSelectedImage: withFinishedUnselectedImage:
```

It was working till now. But suddenly it stopped displaying images.

I tried below various options :

```
[img imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

[tabBarItem setSelectedImage:img];
[tabBarItem setImage:img];

[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:title image:img selectedImage:img];
```

None of them is working. Here, `img` is the image downloaded from URL.

Then I tried with one of the images in app resource and it was displaying.

After that, I tried using temporary `UIImageView` with background color to red and set `img` to this `UIImageView`, it displayed red color instead of `img`.

But strange part is that I use the same `img` in other view controllers where it is displayed correctly.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is it not displaying any image at all, or your image looks like a white square. In my case, my tab bar was used to display me a white square for icons which didn't fit the sizes of this link : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html

Comment: @zbMax It is not displayed at all.

Comment: can you add the code you are using to retrieve your images?

Comment: @zbMax I download image and use in many other screens before reaching this screen. Basically these are profile pictures of user's facebook/google plus accounts. As it works in other screens I don't think there is any problem with downloading.

Comment: Geek can you please reset simulator and restart Xcode may be solve your problem also clean cmd+shift+k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake in code. I had to initialze `img` to some `UIImage` on declaration.
Below is shown what was the issue.

```
UIImage * img;  // Image not initialized

// This condition was not satisfied and hence `img` was not storing any time.
if (condition)
{
    img = ...;
}

// Below condition should have been satisfied if `img` was not initialized.
// But it did not. I am not getting why.
if (!img)
{
    NSLog(@"Image is nil");
}

[tabBarItem setImage:img];
```